# How do you server-side render an angular app using angular universal and use an ssl certificate?

Tags: angular, ssl, angular-universal

Usually if I want my angular apps to run locally over https I will install a certificate and do this in the angular.json file:

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "whatever:build",
        "ssl": true,
        "sslCert": "server.crt",
        "sslKey": "server.key"
      }
```

This spins the app up using a local certificate - but will not use it for an actual deployment.

My angular universal app has the same setup but I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: localStorage and sessionStorage not supported
```

It is quite self-explanatory why that failed, but I cant find any docs on the correct way to do this.

I am using this architect property to build my server files but ssl is not an option here.

```
    "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      }
    }
```

Any tips?

EDIT: this problem persists when deploying the app and using a server driven ssl setup instead of these local ssl files. The first time the app is visited the error appears, after that the server runs fine until we deploy again..

Comment: where is localStorage and sessionStorage being called?

Comment: it gets called from the built server.js file - but that file is using code from angular universal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that there is a service which is using local storage through a node package and of course when that runs on the server it fails. Makes sense.

Need to figure out what my code needs to do, if anything at all, when server side rendering.